# Return image urls with specific base string?

Tags: database

I have two wordpress sites on the same server (for ref call them site1 and site2). site2 hotlinks some images from site1. The problem is I recently used a CDN on site1 and told the CDN to disable hotlinking - this has meant that the images that site2 hotlinks from site1 can no longer be accessed. The CDN can get round this if I place all the images that I need from site1 in a certain folder on site1's directory. So I need to find all the images that are hotlinked from site1 by site2 and place them in this folder.

So I am looking to find referenced images with - http://site1/wp-content/uploads/% - in site2's database, can anyone help?

Comment: The answer here may not be an SQL query, you should edit your question to the generic case so that it doesn't prevent non-SQL answers

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the advice, I have edited as appropriate